# Как обрезать текст после последнего слеша на C#?

Tags: c#

Есть строка

```
C:\Folder1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

Мне надо обрезать всё за последним слешем и получить

```
C:\Folder1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2
```

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Вапиант 1:**

```
var path = @"C:\Folder1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3";
var result = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Для справки: [GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Вариант 2:**

```
var path = @"C:\Folder1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3";
int pos = path.LastIndexOf("\\"); // позиция последнего слеша
var result = path.Remove(pos, path.Length - pos);
```

Результат:

> C:\Folder1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2

Comment: а если это воспринимается, как текст?Это на другом компьютере.На нём надо получить новую строку и отправить. Тоесть это должен быть текст, без System.IO.Path

Comment: Благодарю. Второй вариант-то что надо

Comment: @RakzinRoman а чем вам System.IO.Path не угодил и что вы понимаете под "воспринимается как текст"?

Comment: Ruslan_K, а почему не Substring?

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, потому что второй вариант не поможет при наличии N слешей в конце (где N >= 2)